# Trace on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^k) \mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_\pi} \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^k)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-distributions, micro-local-analysis

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908051/trace-on-mathcals-mathbbrk-hat-otimes-pi-mathcals-mathbb) on Math StackExchange, but it did not receive an answer, despite my offering a bounty to attract attention. I am unsure whether it is appropriate for this venue, but I thought that I would try my luck. Below I have reproduced the question with some modifications.

Let $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ denote the $k$-dimensional Schwartz space with the usual topology, and let $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^k)$ denote its strong dual (i.e. the space of tempered distributions equipped with the topology of uniform convergence on bounded sets). Let $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^k) \mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_\pi} \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ denote the completed projective tensor product of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ and $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^k)$. Note that since both the Schwartz space and the space of tempered distributions are nuclear, the projective tensor product coincides with the injective tensor product.

If $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ and $g\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^k)$, then we can define
$$\operatorname{Tr}(f\otimes \bar{g}) := \overline{\langle{g, \bar{f}}\rangle}_{\mathcal{S}'-\mathcal{S}},$$
where $\langle{\cdot,\cdot}\rangle_{\mathcal{S}'-\mathcal{S}}$ denotes the duality pairing. Now if the duality pairing *were* a continuous map
$$\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^k) \times \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^k) \rightarrow \mathbb{C},$$
then by the universal property of the $\pi$-tensor product, we would obtain a unique continuous map
$$\operatorname{Tr}: \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^k) \mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_\pi} \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^k) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
with the property that $\operatorname{Tr}(f\otimes \bar{g})$ is as above.

Unfortunately, the duality pairing is [not continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908051/trace-on-mathcals-mathbbrk-hat-otimes-pi-mathcals-mathbb), it is only separately continuous--this is a general feature of non-normable locally convex spaces. Therefore, the preceding approach fails, which leads me to my question.

> **Question 1.** Is there a "canonical" way to define a trace $\operatorname{Tr}$ on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^k) \mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_\pi} \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^k)$ (i.e. a linear map such that $\operatorname{Tr}(f\otimes\bar{g}) = \overline{\langle{g,\bar{f}}\rangle}$)?

It seems that such a map $\operatorname{Tr}$ cannot be continuous $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^k)\hat{\otimes}\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^k) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, otherwise, since the canonical bilinear map
$$\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^k)\times\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^k) \rightarrow \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^k) \mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_\pi} \mathcal{S}' (\mathbb{R}^k), \qquad (f,g) \mapsto f\otimes g$$
is continuous, we would have the continuity of the evaluation map.

> **Question 2.** If the answer to Question 1 is no, is there a non-canonical way of defining a trace $\operatorname{Tr}$ on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^k) \mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_\pi}\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^k)$ in such a way that if $\gamma\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^k) \mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_\pi} \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^k)$ and can be identified with an element of trace-class operators on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^k)$, then $\operatorname{Tr}$ coincides with the usual definition of trace?

Answer (score 8):

Q1: No. You gave a proof above: $\overline{\langle f,\bar g\rangle} = \operatorname{Tr}(f\otimes g)$.

Q2: No, if $\operatorname{Tr}$ is supposed to be continuous. Namely, $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^k)\subset L^2(\mathbb R^k)$ continuosly, and $L^2(\mathbb R^k)\subset \mathcal S'(\mathbb R^k)$ countinuous and dense. So any continuous trace would immediately lead to a contradiction to Q1.

Answer (score 4):

In the "classical theory of topological vector spaces" the questions like this are intricated (in my opinion, this is an artifical complexity, the Nature can't be so complicated). But in the [theory of stereotype spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype_space) they become simple: for each stereotype space $X$ (including ${\mathcal S}({\mathbb R}^k)$, since it is also stereotype as a Fréchet space) the pairing
$$
(x,f)\in X\times X^\star\mapsto f(x)\in{\mathbb C}
$$ 
is a [continuous bilinear map in the stereotype sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype_space#Universality_of_tensor_product), and, as a corollary, it can be extended to a continuous linear functional on the ["projective stereotype tensor product"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype_space#Ste_as_a_*-autonomous_category) $\circledast$ (this is an analog of $\hat{\otimes}_\pi$ in the stereotype theory)
$$
\operatorname{cont}: X\circledast X^\star\to {\mathbb C}.
$$
This functional is called a "contraction", you can look at the details in [my paper of 2003](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1020929201133) (page 265).

If you want to define a trace for all operators $\varphi:X\to X$ that are images of the tensors $\alpha\in X\circledast X^\star$ under the [Grothendieck transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype_space#Grothendieck_transformation) $X\circledast X^\star\to{\mathcal L}(X)$, then your space $X$ must have the [stereotype approximation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype_space#Stereotype_approximation_property). As far as I know, nobody was interested up to now, whether the space ${\mathcal S}({\mathbb R}^k)$ has the stereotype approximation, but at first glance this is true: one can try to use the same trick as I did in [my paper of 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.01340) for the space ${\mathcal C}(G)$ of continuous functions on a locally compact group $G$. Also Albrecht Pietsch writes in his [Nuclear locally convex spaces](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642876677), 10.3.2, that the [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) form a basis in the space ${\mathcal S}'({\mathbb R})$ (which coincides with the stereotype dual space ${\mathcal S}({\mathbb R})^\star$). I think something similar must be true for each ${\mathcal S}'({\mathbb R}^k)$ (with arbitrary $k\in{\mathbb N}$), and if so, then ${\mathcal S}'({\mathbb R}^k)={\mathcal S}({\mathbb R}^k)^\star$ and ${\mathcal S}({\mathbb R}^k)$ have the stereotype approximation property.